# How to use html in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp-model

I am new to CakePHP and have a problem in `html->link`. I want to have see more on every post but it is working on only one pos.

**Code:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showMoreComment(<?php echo $rprt_data['CountedComment']?>,<?php echo $rprt_data['Issue']['IssueId']?>)">View <?php echo $rprt_data['CountedComment']-3;?> earlier comments</a>
```

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showMoreComment(<?php echo $rprt_data['CountedComment']?>,<?php echo $rprt_data['Issue']['IssueId']?>)">View <?php echo $rprt_data['CountedComment']-3;?> earlier comments</a>                                                    my programm is like this, please help

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    'View ' . ($rprt_data['CountedComment'] - 3) . ' earlier comments',
    'javascript:showMoreComment(' . $rprt_data['CountedComment'] .', ' . $rprt_data['Issue']['IssueId'] .')'
);
```

If you are still having a problem, please paste the rest of the code from that view